# How to test a method with an infinite loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a method that continuously polls a queue for messages. I'd like to test that a message gets passed to the correct class. How do I do this. Say I have this code:

```
def receive_messages(queue):
    """
    Loops forever, polling the queue for messages.
    """
    while True:
        messages_to_delete = []
        for message in queue.receive_messages():
            try:
                ProcessorFactory(message)().process
```

I'd like to pass this a dummy queue and test that a mock `ProcessorFactory` receives the right messages. How would I do this without winding up in the infinite loop?

Comment: Can you change the code you're trying to test? The easiest way would be to extract the body of the loop into its own method and then test that.

Comment: I don't really want to change the method here just to make it easier to test.